# linux start script.sh when boot is ended

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, sh

i need to start a simple script in command line when all of services is started (like picture ) automatically always when computer is turning on

[image: linux service]

the script is simple, start also a c++ program ./program

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/my/script.sh
```

i need this to connect with anoter simple program like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('data.php')
        }, 3000);
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start a program on boot, you can modify and add a line on /etc/rc.local

e.g.

```
/path/to/my/script.sh &
```

Comment: al kind of scrpit ? also an c++ execute ? ./myProgram ?

Comment: if you want to launch the program instead of the script, get the full path of your program (by `pwd`), and then put the line `/path/to/my/program &` into `/etc/rc.local`